# Calling .getDescribe() on result of SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, describesobject

If I have an SOQL query as follows, which returns only 1 field.

```
String this_soql = 'SELECT SUM(My_Field__c) myField FROM My_Object__c WHERE Id=: the_Id GROUP BY Id';

SObject r = Database.query(this_soql);
```

Can I then go on to get the 'getDescribe' of that field somehow?
Somthing like this perhaps? (which doesnt work)

```
System.debug(r.getDescribe().isAccessible());
```

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the describe method via the [SObject's SObjectType](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObjectType) like this:

```
System.debug(r.getSObjectType().getDescribe().isAccessible());
```

Comment: Perfect! Cheers for the quick response Keith C!